# NodeJs Returning data from async fetch on a variable to reuse

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, asynchronous, promise

I'v been searching around for a few hours (with no success) on how to have an async function return a result, store it in a variable outside the function and reuse that data.

My issue is that I fetch the same data over and over in a few of my functions which seems unnecessary.

Basically this is what I want, and right now it's returning a promise.

```
    let leads;
    try {
        var result = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/lds');
        leads = await result.json();
        return leads;

    } catch (e) {
        // handle error
        console.error(e)
    }
}

var results = readDb();
console.log(results);
```

For example, initially I run a function fetch the data and create a table.

Secondly I run another function that fetches the same data to create pagination buttons.

Thirdly I run another function that fetches the same data, yet again, and listens for the pagination button click to show the data of the corresponding page number.

Ideally I would fetch the data only once.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are using `async/await` you need to `await` the value, however it is only available in an `async` function. You can reuse a variable outside the function to store the value once it is loaded.

```
// reuse leads variable
let leads;

// async function to populate/return leads
async function readDb() {
  // only populate if it is undefined
  if (typeof leads === 'undefined') {
    const result = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/lds');
    leads = await result.json();
  }
  // return just loaded or referenced value
  return leads;
}

// call the function asynchronously 
(async function(){
  // await the results here inside an async function
  const results = await readDb();
  console.log(results);
}());
```

Comment: Hello! So basically I should wrap all the functions I would want to use the fetched results inside another async function. Does that makes sense? Thanks!

Comment: It's all asynchronous so you have to think about when each piece of code will (likely) be executed. The `async function()` at the bottom will be called first, then it would call `readDb()` but needs to wait for the calls to `await fetch()` to resolve before finally returning the result so that you can `console.log()` it.

Comment: Cool, I think i'm getting it. I'll try to adapt the async function at the bottom to my use case, see if it works.

Comment: You can do the same thing with callbacks or `Promises`, but it's easier to read with `async/await` (and still uses promises if you need them).

Comment: Notice the that the function at the bottom is automatically called by defining it as `(async function() {}());` with the `()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working just fine when adapted to my functions. Will mark this as accepted. Final question, I have a user button which ultimately updates the db and the values in the front. Onclick I should first set the reuse variable to null and then execute `readDb()` again, right?

Answer (score 0):

We can define `leads` outside the function and check if it's necessary to fetch it:

```
let leads;
const getLeads = async function() {

    try {
        if (!leads) { // fetch leads only they weren't already loaded
            const result = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/lds');
            leads = await result.json();
        }
        return leads;

    } catch (e) {
        // handle error
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @alfasin, so I tried running the getLeads function and logging the leads variable and Im getting undefined. Could you clarify how to use this approach? Thanks :)

Comment: @JerónimoLlacay I'll need to see your code in order to understand what went wrong

Comment: I think i understood why you defined the leads variable outside. So if I run the getLeads on a following async function it will know it was already fetched, right?

Comment: @JerónimoLlacay exactly!